How to delete Testrun from KIWI TCMS by using API?
I want to create a script, that can delete all created testruns. But I can't find a method for it.
May be there is another way to delete testrun by using api?
For example, testcase have a 'remove' method, but i can't find the same method for testrun.

"remove" method for testrun will be added in version 13.5
